# Sitecore mail template with rich text field

Tags: razor, sitecore, sitecore8

Im trying to create a custom mail system in Sitecore. For this i want to be able to use razor code inside my mail item in the Sitecore backend. This code will be place inside the body field which will be a rich text. Currently I'm working on a Sitecore 8 instance.

Now here is my problem. Whenever I put a piece of code like:

```
@for (var i = 0; i > @model.persons.count;  i++){
```

the rich text fields changes the line of code to:

```
@for (var i = 0; i &lt; @model.documents.count;  i++){
```

or even worse..

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening and what I can do to prevent this. Cause now it changes every time somebody wants to make a change to the email message and it is quite annoying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can write a code inside a Rich Text field in Sitecore that will be then executed while rendering the item / email.

Comment: When i add the code snippet from above while showing the raw values it works like a charm. Just wondering if there is a way without having to use the raw values view each time somebody has to edit the message.

Comment: Like Marek I didn't realise you could put code there - but with some tweaking you can modify how the rich text field re-formats the content you enter: https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/ever-wished-the-rich-text-field-didnt-mess-with-your-html/ (This was written for SC6.x but it probably works similarly in the more recent releases)

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario I would use some  kind of token in the rich text email message field. E.g $persondata$.

Then I would use a pipeline processor to replace the tokens in the email with the real data. This keeps it nice and clean and is easier for editors.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this approach as well, using the RazorEngine to parse the richtext with a dynamic model, still use it actually. But I try to refrain from doing anything other than writing properties because of the problems you mentioned + customers tend to mess it up anyway because they lack knowledge about razor syntax and theres no intellisense to help them.

I would opt to have another rich text field for a single document.

```
<li>@model.documentName - @model.documentPrice</li>
```

And iterate/parse the documents before you stuff it into a model.parseddocuments property. That way you only need to apply

```
<ul>@model.parseddocuments</ul>
```